# Make a view full-width with a ListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I'm trying to make a View in a ListView (through a ListAdapter) with full width.
Here is the current test code :

```
LinearLayout result = new LinearLayout(context);

TextView testView = new TextView(context);
testView.setText("Aaah");
TextView test2View = new TextView(context);
test2View.setText("Eeeeh");

result.addView(testView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
result.addView(test2View, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

// To make it easier to see borders
result.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

(It has to be put in the ListAdapter's createView)

Unfortunately, the two TextViews are small and both stuck on the left.
The limiter is actually the result view itself, not taking full width, so the two TextViews simply share this little space.

Doesn anyone know how to make them take full width ? Thanks ! :)

---

### EDIT : simplified (and almost identical) problem :

---

Code :
http://pastebin.com/6pn1hXnT

I want the TextView to be full-sized, and I center the text so I can see when it is full-width and when it is only wrapping content.
This code shows the text on the left, so the MATCH_PARENT is not doing anything...

What should I do ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

I faced the similar problem and I've followed the advice on this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Ylgekx-A2Xw). The linked topic refers to a ListView inside a dialog, but I've experienced the same behaviour in a pop-up list. In order to make the TextView full-width, I had to wrap it inside a RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/
android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="14dip"
    android:paddingRight="15dip"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_dialog_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add them with fill_parent, but with '0'?

```
result.addView(testView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FILL_PARENT ,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
```

Comment: Because there is two views : I want each to take half the total width only.
I found a solution, but now a great one : 

result.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(totalWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

But it requires to know the total desired width. For some reason, putting LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT doesn't work here O_o

Comment: Yeah, no change :-/ Also, I editted the post to show an even simpler version of the problem.